# Symfony FileFormField - Testing (WebTestCase) multiple file upload

Tags: forms, symfony

In my Symfony web application I have a form allowing multiple file upload (easily done by setting the `multiple` property of the `FileType` equal to `true`). And this works fine: I can select multiple files and upload them. Processing the form and getting all uploaded files also goes fine. But of course, I want to **foresee an integration test** (*`WebTestCase`*) **but I don't find any possibility to simulate a multiple file upload.**

What I have now:

```
...
$uploadedFile = new UploadedFile(...);
$form = ...; // get the form from the crawler
$form['formtype[filename]'][0]->upload($uploadedFile);
$this->client->submit($form);
...
```

That works fine.

But now I want to upload 2 files by 1 form submission (*because the processing logic can behave differently when multiple files are uploaded at once*). **How can I do this**? When I look at http://api.symfony.com/3.0/Symfony/Component/DomCrawler/Field/FileFormField.html I don't see any way to pass in, for example, an array of `UploadedFile` objects. Anyone experience with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `multiple` property is set, crawler creates a file form field array with single `FileFormField` field. One field can hold a single file so you need multiple fields for multiple files. I came to a solution by manually adding more `FileFormField` to the form.

```
$form = ...
// get file field node in DOM
$node = $crawler->filter("input[name='formtype[filename][]']")->getNode(0);

// add additional fields to form (you can create as many as you need)
$newField = new FileFormField($node);
$form->set($newField);
...
// set files with upload()
$form['formtype[filename]'][0]->upload($uploadedFile1);
$form['formtype[filename]'][1]->upload($uploadedFile2);
...

//or with submit values 
$crawler->submit($form, [
  ...
 'formtype[filename]' => [$uploadedFile1, $uploadedFile2]

]);
```